# How can I reduce this code to use only one while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Here's my code so far:

```
public class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100: ");
      int e = 50;
      while (e <= 100) {
         System.out.print(" " + e);
         e += 2;
      }

      System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: ");
      int i = 51;
      while (i <= 100) {
         System.out.print(" " + i);
         i += 2;
      }
   }
}
```

How can I reduce these two while loops to just one while loop?

Comment: That depends on if you want the program to function in the same way

Comment: There's no way to do it without interleaving the even and odd numbers.

Comment: What does it matter? In both cases your program will execute 100 println, comparison and addition.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir, does it matter if it does? Purposes of questions should not be discussed (Sorry I don't mean to replace any moderation, I just felt like it was right to say it)

Answer (score 2):

Store the numbers in two `StringBuilder`s, one for the odd numbers and the other for the even numbers :

```
public class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      StringBuilder even = new StringBuilder();
      StringBuilder odd = new StringBuilder();

      int e = 50;
      while (e <= 100) {
         if (e%2 == 0)
             even.append (" " + e);
         else
             odd.append (" " + e);
         e++;
      }
      System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100: " + even.toString());
      System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: " + odd.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[]args)
       {
          StringBuilder evenString = new StringBuilder("Even numbers between 50 and 100: ");
          StringBuilder oddString = new StringBuilder("Odd numbers between 50 and 100: ");
          int e = 50;
          while (e <= 100) {
             if((e % 2) == 0)
             {
                 evenString.append(" " + e);
             }
             else
             {
                 oddString.append(" " + e);
             }
             e++;
          }
          System.out.println(evenString);
          System.out.println(oddString);
       }
```

Use a two StringBuilders to store the strings you want to display then write them out after your done looping.  Each loop do modular division (%) to see if its even or odd.  If the remainder is 0 then it's even if it's not then it's odd.  Based on which one it is just append it to the appropriate StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing code duplication is often a good thing. The most basic tool that Java provides are methods, so you could extract the behavior of your loop in a method and write an equivalent program:

```
public class EvenOdd
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100: ");
        printEverySecondNumber(50, 100);

        System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: ");
        printEverySecondNumber(51, 100);
    }

    public static void printEverySecondNumber(int start, int end){
        int current = start;
        while (current <= end) {
            System.out.print(" " + current);
            current += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this program behaves just the same: The loop will stil get executed twice, but it is not duplicated in code.

Comment: This still has 2 loops. Try doing one of the solutions below if you want to eliminate the extra 50 iterations.

Comment: There is only one loop, but the loop is executed twice. Obviously there will be no benefit in performance (or the performance may even decrease since there is an additional method dispatch). However, code duplication is reduced while keeping the original behavior. I'd also favor a solution with a string builder though, because it separates the creation of the string from outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

Use lists. They print out nicely.

```
public class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
     List<String> even = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> odd = new ArrayList<String>();

      int e = 50;
      while (e <= 100) {
         if (e%2 == 0)
             even.add(String.valueOf(e));
         else
             odd.add(String.valueOf(e));
         e++;
      }
      System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100: " + even);
      System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: " + odd);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without storing numbers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0; 
    System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100: ");
    while (i <= 50) {
        if (i == 26) { 
            System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100: ");
        }
        if (i <= 25) {
            System.out.print (" " + (2 * i + 50));
        } else {
            System.out.print (" " + (2 * (i - 25) + 49));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to do a single loop

```
int n = 50;
System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100:");
while(n < 151){
    if(n <= 100)
        System.out.print(" " + n);
    else
        System.out.print(" " + (n-50));

    if(n != 100)
        n = n + 2;
    else{
        System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100:");
        n = n + 1;
    }
}
```

The benefit to this is you aren't building any unnecessary objects or having to manage anything other than n really.

If your goal is to reduce loop iterations

```
StringBuilder evenString = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder oddString = new StringBuilder();

int n = 50;
while(n <= 100){
    evenString.append(" " + n);
    if(n != 100)
        oddString = oddString.append(" " + (n + 1));
    n = n + 2;
}

System.out.println("Even numbers between 50 and 100:" + evenString);
System.out.print("Odd numbers between 50 and 100:" + oddString);
```

Something to notice, `this cuts your iterations in half over using a single while with if statements`.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-start iterations by re-setting the counter:

```
public class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      int e = 0;
      while (1) {
         if (e==0) {
             System.out.print("Even numbers between 50 and 100:");
             e = 50;
         }
         else
         if (e==102) { 
             System.out.print("\nOdd numbers between 50 and 100:");
             e = 51;
         }
         else
         if (e==101) { 
             System.out.print("\n");
             break;
         }

         System.out.print(" " + e);
         e += 2;
      }
   }
}
```